# WCF 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 comparison?

Tags: c#, wcf

I just wondering in WCF just wanted to know the difference between the WCF 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5.

Is there any advantages in using WCF 4.5 over WCF 4.0?

Answer (score 6):

1. What’s new in WCF 4.5? let’s start with WCF configuration
2. What’s new in WCF 4.5? a single WSDL file
3. What’s new in WCF 4.5? Configuration tooltips and intellisense in config files
4. What’s new in WCF 4.5? Configuration validations
5. What’s new in WCF 4.5? Multiple authentication support on a single endpoint in IIS
6. What’s new in WCF 4.5? Automatic HTTPS endpoint for IIS
7. What’s new in WCF 4.5? BasicHttpsBinding
8. What’s new in WCF 4.5? Changed default for ASP.NET compatibility mode

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2012/01/17/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-improved-streaming-in-iis-hosting.aspx